# Replace a letter with another in an entire Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a Wordpress website for a Danish shipping agency in based Germany, and they want the homepage to automatically transform the letter "ø/Ø" to the letter "ö/Ö".

I have made a PHP function/program where I replace the ø/Ø to ö/Ö, from the $string.

But how can I make it check all letters in a Wordpress page?

```
<?php
$string = "Öýra Bibendum Trisö tique agergöet dellentesque Öibendum Öristique gmet reölentesqueö.";
$newSmall = "ö";
$oldSmall = "ø";
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($oldSmall, $newSmall, $string);
$newLarge = "Ö";
$oldLarge = "Ø";
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($oldLarge, $newLarge, $onlyconsonants);

echo $onlyconsonants;

?>
```

Comment: Quickly: javascript to replace the letters... But be careful of hrefs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

**1. Use a plugin** (probably the best way):

Take a look at [this one](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-search-and-replace-wordpress-in-blog-post/) that can do the work for you.

It's described as:

> Lets you find and replace text in pages, posts, Custom Post types and
>   trashed items with a GUI. Optional: postmeta and low_priority updates

**2. Replace the content on the Database**

This query should do the trick:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (  
post_content,  
'Item to replace here',  
'Replacement text here');
```

Full tutorial [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-search-and-replace-wordpress-in-blog-post/)

Do a backup before any of the processes.